# how to start uwamp as an background process and how to get notified server is ready in windows os?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, uwamp

need to start PHP , APACHE , MYSQL using UWAMP or any as Background process without showing tray icon or any ?
using command line start  -WindowStyle Hidden its not working. kindly suggest me something for this.

Answer (score 0):

use the commands prompt to start the application in the windows, almost all programming language is able of use this recurse, I'm use in java language with these commands:

//class for use the commands in the prompt of the windows OS

public class Prompt {

```
public static String exec(String cmd) {
    String resposta = "";
    try {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).getInputStream());
        while (S.hasNextLine()) {
            resposta += S.nextLine() + "\n";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Alert.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return resposta;
}

public static void open(String cmd) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Alert.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

}
}

// method in another class for start programs like a service

public static void start() {

```
    try {

        String file = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

        String startApache = file + "/UwAmp/bin/apache/bin/httpd.exe  -k -start";
        String startMySql = file + "/UwAmp/bin/database/mysql-5.7.11/bin/mysqld.exe";

        System.out.println("beginning Apache Server");
        Prompt.exec(startApache);
        Thread.sleep(500);

       System.out.println("beginning MySQL Database Server");
        Prompt.exec(startMySql);
        Thread.sleep(500);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Alert.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```